# Advanced tooltip with divs

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip, qtip2

I'm using `qTip2` with the 'Dark' theme. I want to customize it to look similar to an MMORPG ([Diablo 3](http://www.numerama.com/media/attach/diablo3-legendary-item-drop2.jpg)).

Is this possible with this plugin? Or is this possible with another tooltip plugin?

[Here](http://qtip2.com/guides#style.html) is the default look which we can target with css to customize it. I am, however, looking for a more advanced look.

Here's the [code](http://liveweave.com/nPGnhh).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to get the best responses to your questions, it is best to lay out all of the research you've done, procedures you've followed and code you've tried in the question itself. This prevents people helping you from working in a vacuum or replicating work you've already done! To learn how to compose a _great_ question, please refer to this: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I did it. With qTip2 it is possible to build an HTML structure and use it in the title.

For example:

```
<div id="my-div" title="<div id='div-title'>Hello World!</div>"></div>
```

Of course we can use PHP, so for example it would look like:

```
<?php
   $title = 'Hello World';
?>
<div id="my-div" title='<?php echo $title ?>'></div>
```

**BE AWARE!** This plugin needs a single quote or it will break our structure, so when you use a variable in the string you have to do that this way:

```
<?php
   $part = 'World';
   $title = 'Hello' . $part . '!';
?>
<div id="my-div" title='<?php echo $title ?>'></div>
```